# Six counters are tossed. How many outcomes are possible if the six counters are distinguishable? Indistinguishable?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, combinations

Counters are kind of like coins with two different colours on each side. By distinguishable I mean that each of the 6 counters has different colours. For instance, 1= blue and green, 2= red and black, 3= silver and golden, and so on..

So how many outcomes are possible if the counters are distinguishable.

Comment: What do you mean by indistinguishable? All of them Red/Blue? Then the number of outcomes is 6+1 = 7 (i.e. # Reds). If they are distinguishable as you indicated, then the number of outcomes is $2^6$=64, at least for my interpretation of "distinguishable" which does not include random orderings (I mean toss them simultaneously). If you ALSO include the order in which they are tossed as being part of the experiment and the outcome, then you'd get 64 and 64*720, respectively, as in the answer by SS below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take each counter one by one. Now each one of them has two possibilities irrespective of the outcomes of the other counters. In short each counter has results which are independent of the other counters.

So let's say if there was only one counter. Then the answer would simply be $2$. If there were two counters, for each outcome of the first, we have two of the second. Thereby giving us

$$N = 2*2 = 4$$

Extrapolating this philosophy for $6$ counters, we have

$$N = 2*2*2*2*2*2 = 2^6 = 64$$

So number of outcomes is $64$. Keep in mind that this is the total number of possibiliyies if you fix the order of flipping i.e. say that Blue/Green is flipped $1st$, Red/Black is flipped $2nd$ and so on so forth. If the order is not fixed either, you multiply this with $6!$ (number of permutations of counters), you get

$$N = 64*6! = 46080$$

If the counters are indistinguishable, this becomes a multiple coin toss problem with no permutations possible as coins are all same and total no of outcomes as

$$N = 64$$

I am also attaching a link of a basic coin toss guide

http://www.probabilityformula.org/coin-toss-probability.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This is great! But why do we multiply by 6! instead of adding?

Comment: Because for each outcome of the tosses, there are 6! factorial ways to arrange them in order. Here is a basic permutation guide for you to look at

https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Happy to help !